# Mask minimum values per group in a `pd.DataFrame`

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a `pd.DataFrame` containing different time series in different groups, I want to create a mask over all rows that indicates per `group` at which `time`points the minima of `value` is reached in respect of `type` `0`:

For example, given the `pd.DataFrame`:

```
>>> df
      group  type  time  value
0     A     0     0      4
1     A     0     1      5
2     A     1     0      6
3     A     1     1      7
4     B     0     0     11
5     B     0     1     10
6     B     1     0      9
7     B     1     1      8
```

In `group` `A` the minima for `type` `0` is reached at the `time`point `0`. For `group` `B` the minima for `type` `0` is reached at the `time`point `1`. Therefore, the resulting column should look like:

```
      is_min
0     True
1     False
2     True
3     False
4     False
5     True
6     False
7     True
```

I have created a version that seems very cumbersome, first finding out the minima locations and then constructing the final column:

```
def get_minima(df):
    type_mask = df.type == 0
    min_value = df[type_mask].value.min()
    value_mask = df.value == min_value
    return df[type_mask & value_mask].time.max()

min_ts = df.groupby('group').apply(get_minima)
df['is_min'] = df.apply(lambda row: min_ts[row.group] == row.time, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try with `groupby`+`apply` and `min`

```
df['is_min']= df.groupby(['group','type'])['value']
                .apply(lambda x: x==x.min())
```

---

Same as this with `transform`+`min` to get the minimal and `eq` to create the mask desired:

```
df['is_min']= df.groupby(['group','type'])['value']
                .transform('min').eq(df['value'])
```

---

Output:

```
df
  group  type  time  value  is_min
0     A     0     0      4    True
1     A     0     1      5   False
2     A     1     0      6    True
3     A     1     1      7   False
4     B     0     0     11   False
5     B     0     1     10    True
6     B     1     0      9   False
7     B     1     1      8    True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the rows with an excluding `merge`. `sort` the values, subset to only `"type==0"` and `drop_duplicates` to get the times per group you need to exclude. Then merge with an indicator to exclude.

```
m = (df.sort_values('value').query('type == 0').drop_duplicates('group')
       .drop(columns=['type', 'value']))
#  group  time
#0     A     0
#5     B     1

df = (df.merge(m, how='outer', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"')
        .drop(columns='_merge'))

  group  type  time  value
2     A     0     1      5
3     A     1     1      7
4     B     0     0     11
5     B     1     0      9
```

---

If you separately need the mask and don't want to automatically `query` to subset the rows, `map` the indicator

```
df = df.merge(m, how='outer', indicator='is_min')
df['is_min'] = df['is_min'].map({'left_only': False, 'both': True})

  group  type  time  value is_min
0     A     0     0      4   True
1     A     1     0      6   True
2     A     0     1      5  False
3     A     1     1      7  False
4     B     0     0     11  False
5     B     1     0      9  False
6     B     0     1     10   True
7     B     1     1      8   True
```